# Which architecture should be used while developing iOS Application?

Tags: ios, iphone, architecture

I am going to start a new application in iOS and there are multiple architectures available in iOS i.e Viper,MVVM,MVP and MVC.

I have search google but didn't find any specific use of these architectures.

Can anyone please guide me that when and which architecture should be used and which is more beneficial?

Comment: I am quite young about it but there is this post that helps me to understand the advantages and disadvantages of each design pattern : https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-architecture-patterns-ecba4c38de52

Comment: Given that all of the above have advantages and drawbacks, this question will only cause opinion's to be expressed and can not be answered deterministically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to put my answer in short:

**MVC:** This is the basic architecture you will find most of the people use. Without knowing this, don't go forward as it's wasting time doing so. But this architecture no one is interested in the current market as it has few drawbacks. When comes to unit testing people find it difficult. So they started moving on. One good thing about this architecture is your development is super fast.

**VIPER:** which became very popular these days for its separation of data, design, controller logic. For unit testing, it will be very nice. But understanding and putting efforts in this are more. If you fully understand this one, I advise you to go.

**MVP:** People who understand MVC, can easily go with this MVP. As there are not many changes involved in this from MVC. Presentation logic will be separated out. If you want to build good architecture, not the basic one go for this.

**MVVM:** It also requires good efforts from you. Don't go until you understood. Again very good separation of model, View, ViewModel.

Now it's your choice to get onboard. As all of us know, how important an architecture is for an app, don't take fast decisions here. Take your own time and conclude based on the time you have in your hands, the need for proper architecture.